# Access Users Contacts Phone Numbers CNContacts

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I am trying to get to phone numbers of my contacts using CNContact, i want to have the number as a simple string of its didgits such as `"04xxxxxxxx"` but the closest I can get to is the following. ("contact" is of type CNContact)

```
contact.phoneNumbers[0].value
\\Which prints: <CNPhoneNumber: 0x13560a550: countryCode=au, digits=04xxxxxxxx>
```

ive tried all the obvious things and not so obvious things, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has a more legitimate solution please do post it, otherwise this rather hacky approach works:

```
let value = String(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value)

let start = value.rangeOfString("digits=")!.endIndex
let end = value.endIndex.predecessor()

let number = value.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end))
```

Comment: Yup, works for me as well. Surprised there isn't a less "hacky" approach. Apple should have a subclass of "digits"!

Answer (score 0):

Using this category you can now access the phone number via swift.
don't forget to include this file in the bridging header

```
@implementation  CNPhoneNumber (SwiftSupport)
- (NSString*)toString {
    return self.stringValue;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the number value as follows:

```
let number = value.valueForKey("digits") as! String
```

From iOS9:

```
let number = value.stringValue
```

According to Apple's documentation on CNPhoneNumber:

> stringValue
> Property
> The string value of the phone number. (read-only)
>
> Declaration
> SWIFT
> var stringValue: String { get }